# Ruby, adding multiple objects to an array at once

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have Shop class, and I want to add multiple items at once.
I want this:

```
shop1 = Shop.new
product1 = Product.new("Dress", 50)
shop1.add_products(product1, 5)
```

to add 5 dresses to warehouse

```
def add(product, qty)
  @products << product * qty
end
```

so later I can use

```
@products.select{|p| p.name == "Dress"}.count
```

and get 5. Is it possible?

Comment: Be careful, though: when you do `[item] * 3`, you get an array of three references to the same item, not three items. Altering any of them will affect all the array items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I think is:

```
def add(product, qty)
  @products += [product] * qty
end
```

But it all comes down to your syntax preferences.

Comment: The difference with the `concat` version is that this one creates a new array, instead of adding to the existing one. They're both valid ways to do it. I did an in-place edit because that's what the OP did as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
def add(product, qty)
  @products.concat([product] * qty)
end
```

or less "clever"

```
def add(product, qty)
  qty.times { @products << product }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers will solve your problem. However, maybe you should consider using a hash instead of an array.

Something like this:

```
 class Product    
  @@products = Hash.new(0)

  def initialize(product, qty)
    @@products[product] = qty
  end

  def increase_stock(product, qty)
    @@products[product] += qty
  end

  def decrease_stock(product, qty)
    @@products[product] -= qty
  end

  def count_stock(product)
    @@products[product]
  end
end

p = Product.new('Dress',5)
p.count_stock('Dress')
 => 5
p.increase_stock('Dress',10)
p.count_stock('Dress')
 => 15
p.decrease_stock('Dress',2)
p.count_stock('Dress')
 => 13
```

In my GitHub, there is a [simple command-line inventory management app written in Ruby](https://github.com/brunofacca/udacity-inventory-manager). May be useful..